# Find most significant DWORD in an DWORD array

Tags: algorithm, comparison, assembly

I want to find the most significant DWORD which isn't equal to 0 in an DWORD array. The algorithm should be optimized for data sizes up to 128 byte.

I've made three different functions, which all returns the index of the specific DWORD.

```
unsigned long msb_msvc(long* dw, std::intptr_t n)
{
    while( --n )
    {
        if( dw[n] )
            break;
    }
    return n;
}

static inline unsigned long msb_386(long* dw, std::intptr_t n)
{
    __asm 
    {
        mov ecx, [dw]
        mov eax, [n]

__loop: sub eax, 1
        jz  SHORT __exit
        cmp DWORD PTR [ecx + eax * 4], 0
        jz  SHORT __loop
__exit:
    }
}

static inline unsigned long msb_sse2(long* dw, std::intptr_t n)
{
    __asm 
    {
        mov  ecx, [dw]
        mov  eax, [n]
        test ecx, 0x0f
        jnz  SHORT __128_unaligned

__128_aligned:
        cmp      eax, 4
        jb       SHORT __64
        sub      eax, 4
        movdqa   xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [ecx + eax * 4]
        pxor     xmm1, xmm1
        pcmpeqd  xmm0, xmm1
        pmovmskb edx, xmm0
        not      edx
        and      edx, 0xffff
        jz       SHORT __128_aligned
        jmp      SHORT __exit

__128_unaligned:
        cmp      eax, 4
        jb       SHORT __64
        sub      eax, 4
        movdqu   xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [ecx + eax * 4]
        pxor     xmm1, xmm1
        pcmpeqd  xmm0, xmm1
        pmovmskb edx, xmm0
        not      edx
        and      edx, 0xffff
        jz       SHORT __128_unaligned
        jmp      SHORT __exit

__64:
        cmp      eax, 2
        jb       __32
        sub      eax, 2
        movq     mm0, MMWORD PTR [ecx + eax * 4]
        pxor     mm1, mm1
        pcmpeqd  mm0, mm1
        pmovmskb edx, mm0
        not      edx
        and      edx, 0xff
        emms
        jz       SHORT __64
        jmp      SHORT __exit

__32:
        test eax, eax
        jz   SHORT __exit
        xor  eax, eax
        jmp  __leave ; retn

__exit:
        bsr      edx, edx
        shr      edx, 2
        add eax, edx

__leave:
    }
}
```

These function should be used, to preselect data which will be compared against each other. So, it needs to be performant.

Does anybody know a better algorithm?

Comment: looked at BitScanReverse http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/fbxyd7zd(v=VS.80).aspx or __builtin_clz for non-ms?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. First of all, _BitScanRever and _BitScanForward return the most and least significant BIT (I want to get a byte or dword). Secondly, These functions use bsf and bsr instructions .. nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are just looking for the first non-zero word in a given array. I would definitely go with a simple loop written in C. If there's some reason why this is **super** performance critical, I would recommend you look in the larger context of your program and ask e.g. the question why you need to find the non-zero object from the array and why can't you know its location already.